# How should they bid?

Tags: game-theory

[Picture of Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIczA.jpg)

Gladyn and Don inherit a car worth 800. They agree to settle the ownership by means of sealed bids. The high bidder gets the car by paying his brother the amount of the high bid. If the bids are equal - which they may well be, because they agree to bid in hundred-dollar quantities - the ownership is determined by the toss of a coin, there being no exchange of funds. Gladyn has 500 on hand, whereas Don has 800.

How should they bid?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What's *your* thinking?

Comment: Thanks! I made a matrix for Gladyn's payoffs and found that there is a saddle point at 400. Thus, I think they should each bid $400. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert on game theory ... but I am sure many on this site are.  Why don't you try to show your work in your post so others can comment on that. We discourage just putting questions here (this is not a 'free HW service'), and very much encourage sharing your work and thoughts with us so we can provide focused feedback.

Comment: $\$400$ would be a "fair deal," but each wants something better than a fair deal.  I think each bids $\$300.$

Comment: @Bram28 just added a picture of my work! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

This zero-sum game has more than one saddle-point (both players could bid $3$ or $4$ or play a mixed strategy over those two bids). When a zero-sum game has multiple saddle-points, equilibrium outcomes are *equivalent* (they give the same payoffs) and *interchangeable* (you can swap them). Therefore, from a strategic viewpoint, there are multiple optimal bids (3 or 4,or a mixed strategy).